# Swift HTML Parser

Tags: html, swift, parsing

I am having trouble posting the outputs to a label. I have to covert it to a String? The error it seems to give me is "Cannot subscript a value of type JiNode? with an index of type 'Int'" Please help!

```
var meter = ""

@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("start scraping...")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://uberestimate.com/costs.php")
        let jiDoc = Ji(htmlURL: url!)


        if jiDoc != nil {
            print("html retrived.\n")
            self.scrapeHTML(jiDoc!)
        }
    }

}
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var endingPoint: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var startingpoint: UITextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

private func scrapeHTML(jiDoc: Ji) {
    println("parsing...\n")
    let bodyNode = jiDoc.xPath("//body")!.first!

    var contentDivNode = bodyNode.xPath("//span[@style='font-size:1.3em']").first

    if contentDivNode == nil {
        print("unexpected format!")

    }else{
        var cdnArray = contentDivNode[1]

        var cdn = cdnArray[0]! as String

        self.resultLabel.text = cdn

      //  println(contentDivNode)
    }
return

}
```

}

Comment: You should share the HTML you are dealing with and the error you are getting to let others understand what your problem is

Comment: It is displaying the HTML but it is not displaying on the label. There is a problem the problem starts when i try and convert a node to a string. And then a 'string' into a 'string'. I am confused with how to do that. Thank You                    var cdnArray = contentDivNode[1]

        var cdn = cdnArray[0]! as String

        self.resultLabel.text = cdn

Comment: This is the link to the third party library https://github.com/honghaoz/Ji

Comment: the error is cannot subscript a value of type Jinode? with an index type 'int'  I understand that it can covert directly to a string/array. But how can I covert it into a different type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("start scraping...")

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://uberestimate.com/costs.php")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { data, response, error in
        if data == nil || error != nil {   // in Swift 2, I'd use `guard`, but I tried to keep this backward compatible
            print(error)
            return
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.scrapeHTML(data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

private func scrapeHTML(data: NSData) {
    print("parsing...\n")

    let jiDoc = Ji(data: data, isXML: false)

    if let contentDivNode = jiDoc?.xPath("//span[@style='font-size:1.3em']")?.first {
        self.resultLabel.text = contentDivNode.content
    }
}
```

I'm using the Swift 2.1 (and I infer from the presence of `println` that you must be using an earlier version), but I think this is largely the same regardless of Swift version.

BTW, notice that I am dispatching the update of the label back to the main queue (as you called `scrapeHTML` from a global queue, but UI updates must happen on the main thread). I'm also using `NSURLSession` rather than dispatching a synchronous network request to a global queue.

Comment: That worked! Its a mind blower. I am just a beginner and it helps to know that theres a bundle of resources like you. Thanks. I will pass my knowledge on!